# Does HTML MailTo actually send the e-mail? If so how?

Tags: html

So my question is when we use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h3>
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
   Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
   E-mail:<br>
   <input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
   Comment:<br>
   <input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm asking is: 
does this actually send an email to someone@example.com? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

No, the browser fetches the default mail client. It does not automatically send the e-mail, it simply shorthands the process of opening the mail client and putting certain values such as addresses in the header.

Comment: so is there a way to let the user login to Hotmail, yahoo, etc?

Comment: It does not matter if their default mail client is a webmail client, the browser still uses it for mailto.

Answer (score 0):

No the browser is not capable of sending email.  Usually a server side language, like `PHP` or `JAVA` is used to send the email.  You can find scripts where you can send the data to and it will send an email for you.

Sending an email is a complicated task requiring `ports` to be open and certain `headers` to be sent with the message describing the `To`, `From`, `Subject`, `Body`, and more fields.

`mailto` is a browser shortcut to enable links to be opened in the default client, that the user chooses.

Here's how you can send email using a [PHP Script](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  If you do not have php on your server then you can not use this.

If you want to create an email template the `mailto` supports a few more parameters that can be passed along.  Here's an [example](http://www.addressmunger.com/mailto_syntax_tutorial/).  If you use javascript you can have the user fill in the form, then when they click submit have it open an email, in their default client (including web emails), and have it prefilled for them to click send.

Comment: I think it's a question of choice more than capability. The technological requirements of sending an e-mail are not significantly different than sending an HTTP message, and browsers handle HTTP quite well.The reason browsers don't bother is more likely tied to the fact that you would have to configure the browser like a mail client which is not worth it if the user already has a mail client they like.

Comment: @cookyt No. It's not choice. SMTP is a different protocol from HTTP. Sure you're just sending packets, but then that's like saying making a video game is no different then a web page because they are both sending packets and have a display.

Comment: I'm not saying that you could somehow force a web browser to send an email over SMTP. HTTP and SMTP are different protocols, and the browser isn't designed to handle SMTP. It's just that you mention in your answer that sending email requires opening a port and sending a message with headers. The way you word it sounds like those tasks are impossible for a web browser to accomplish, but the browser does them every time it sends an HTTP request.